# jsp not found in SpringMVC and glassfish

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, glassfish-3

i am working on project. i did some simple changes and now i am getting following error.

```
SEVERE: PWC6117: File "D%3A%5CProjects%5CSampradan%5CGV+UI%5Cui%5CGVUI%5Cbuild%5Cweb%5Cjsp%5Cbarcode%5Csearch.jsp" not found
```

So. i removed all code from jsp and still i am getting error.

my jsp is resides in /jsp/module/search.jsp

my Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView searchBCGenRequest(HttpServletRequest hsr1, HttpServletResponse hsr2, HttpSession session) {


        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.setViewName("/module/search");
        System.out.println(mv.getViewName());
        return mv;
    }
```

it is printing /module/search but after it gives me following error.

```
SEVERE: PWC6117: File "D%3A%5CProjects%5CSampradan%5CGV+UI%5Cui%5CGVUI%5Cbuild%5Cweb%5Cjsp%5Cbarcode%5Csearch.jsp" not found
```

Comment: Have you configured an [InternalResourceViewResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/JstlView.html) in XML or in code?

Comment: yes. and all other pages are working like this. just this page is not working.

Comment: It might be the leading `/`. Does `mv.setViewName("module/search")` work?

Comment: It tries to load \barcode\search.jsp, where could that come from? Is your controller mapped to "/barcode"?

Comment: Tossing the error string in my handy-dandy HTML decoder, I get the path "D:\Projects\Sampradan\GV+UI\ui\GVUI\build\web\jsp\barcode\search.jsp".  Is this, in fact, the correct path to the JSP?